# visual studio dump file and pdb file

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

visual studio require a version matched pdb file to debug the dump file. I feel this is very inconvenient, each time I release the binary file, I need to remember to copy the pdb file to another folder. If I forget do this, then I can not debug the dump file if app crash. Because during the time of release binary file and app crash, I will continue write code and build, the pdb file will refreshed.

Unlike gcc, when core dump generated, I can debug the dump file without anything(app build with -debug). But for vs, if there is not version matched pdb and source code, a dump file will be meaningless.

Is there a good way to cope with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [uploading the PDBs to a symbol server](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/setting-up-your-own-symbolsource-server-step-by-step) after each build and point in the VS debugging options to the symbol server. VS or other debuggers like Windbg fetch the correct symbols on demand.

Comment: keeping every version PDB file is too big. My project's PDB file is bigger than 100MB. MSDN says use /Z7 can let compiler write debug info into obj file, does that work?

Comment: I never used that option. Try it out and tell us the result

Comment: @jean - (1) pushing information from pdb into obj will replicate it through all your users, without reducing the size; it will simply multiply your size problem. (2) pdb files are well compressible (5 to 7 times, according to a quick test). (3) how many versions of your software are there "in the wild"? Those are the only pdb's you need to keep for crash dump debugging.

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein But I don't know which version exe will crash in advance. I will release several version to other department, for example, QA.

Comment: "When the linker generates .dll, executable, and PDB files, it stores identical GUIDs in each file. The GUID is used by tools to determine if a given PDB file matches a DLL or an executable file." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588(v=vs.85).aspx The symbol server and Windbg/VS will do everything you need to get the right files